# cant store the value in global variable

Tags: python, algorithm, recursive-backtracking

Im trying to do permutation problem in leetcode with backtracking Algorithm, While Printing I got all the Possiblities  but when i Trying to store those value in global variable I'm not allow to that

```
Ex:
AnswerIwant:[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]

when i print those value while recursion it is print 
Example:
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

When I store The Value In Global variable for outPut I got like This

```
[1, 2, 3]
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2]]
[1, 3, 2]
[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2]]
[[1, 3], [1, 3]]
[[1], [1]]
[2, 3, 1]
[[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
[[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
[2, 1, 3]
[[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]]
[[2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1]]
[[2], [2], [2], [2]]
[3, 1, 2]
[[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
[[3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]]
[3, 2, 1]
[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
[[3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2]]
[[3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]

[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

**Here Is my code For the Above OutPut**

```
nums = [1,2,3]
val=nums
answerIwant = []
numberOfValues=len(val)-1
answer=[]
def permutation(nums, bucket, index,sub):
    global answerIwant,numberOfValues
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        val=nums.pop(0)
        bucket.append(val)
        if len(bucket)-1==numberOfValues:
            print(bucket)
            answerIwant.append(bucket)
        permutation(nums, bucket, index,sub)
        nev=bucket.pop()
        nums.append(nev)
    print(answerIwant)
#[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
sub=[]
bucket = []

val=(permutation(nums, bucket, index,sub))
print(val)
```

Explain that problem i'm facing with symbol word
**Thank You**

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list

Comment: I Already solved in another Method,I'm Trying to solve this with backtrackg for to learn backtracking i got all my possiblities but the problem is I cant strore those value in global variable I dont have any idea about thhat why it dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the copy of the list during appening in the answerIwant list. So you should replace `answerIwant.append(bucket)` to `answerIwant.append(bucket.copy())`.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it) for more info. So your code could be this,

```
nums = [1,2,3]
val=nums
answerIwant = []
numberOfValues=len(val)-1
answer=[]
def permutation(nums, bucket, index,sub):
    global numberOfValues
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        val=nums.pop(0)
        bucket.append(val)
        if len(bucket)-1==numberOfValues:
            # print(bucket)
            answerIwant.append(bucket.copy())
        permutation(nums, bucket, index,sub)
        nev = bucket
        nev=bucket.pop()
        nums.append(nev)

#[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
sub=[]
bucket = []

permutation(nums, bucket, 0,sub)

print(answerIwant)
```